# typeError al intentar navegar entre pantallas en React Native

Tags: react-native

Estoy siguiendo el tutorial oficial de [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) y en el primer ejemplo de poner un botón en la pantalla `Home`, que redirige a la pantalla `Details`, me salta el error.

Supuestamente hay que poner esta linea:

```
<Button
      title="Go to Details"
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
    />
```

Yo tengo exactamente la misma, con la diferencia que en vez de Details pongo List:

```js
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This the Home Screen</Text>
            <Button title="Ir a la lista más visitada" 
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('List')}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Este es mi código completo y lo he puesto igual que en el tutorial:

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Activity from './screens/Activity'
import Home from './screens/Home'
import List from './screens/List'
import Settings from './screens/Settings'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppContainer />
  );
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home ,
  Activity: Activity,
  List: List ,
  Settings: Settings 
}, {initialRouteName: 'Home'})
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

Y el componente List al que quiero llegar:

```js
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const List = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>The List screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default List
```

He probado en embrazar el onPress en un String() y no ha funcionado. La app sólo me da error cuando pulso el botón. O sea que el error deberia estar en la linea de el `onPress`

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating '_this.props.navigation')
```

Comment: EDITO: Acabo de solucionarlo cambiando las funciones por clases...Si alguien tiene alguna solución para conservar las funciones, lo agradecería.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como pones en tu comentario, la solución para las funciones, sería recibir como parámetros los props. De la siguiente forma:

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This the Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Ir a la lista más visitada" 
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('List')}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Donde `{ navigation }` es el objeto de props que recibe como parámetro, y se está deconstruyendo. También es válido este código:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This the Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Ir a la lista más visitada" 
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('List')}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Gracias. Por cierto, si quiero añadir static navigationOptions = { } dentro de esa función tendría que cambiar algo en concreto? O mejor ese parámetro se reserva para los componentes que deben llevar state.? Es decir solo lo puedo usar en clases.

Comment: Podrías antes de hacer el export definirlo a parte como `Home.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ ... })` de esta forma puede funcionar